# How to extract query string values using a regex?

Tags: regex

My string is:

```
/excursion/popupPortPOI.do?voyageCode=S515&tourCode=&travelOrder=A&portid=SYD
/excursion/popupPortPOI.do?voyageCode=S515&tourCode=&travelOrder=A&portid=BNE
/excursion/popupPortPOI.do?voyageCode=D520&tourCode=&travelOrder=A&portid=JFM
/excursion/popupPortPOI.do?voyageCode=D520&tourCode=&travelOrder=A&portid=SYD
/excursion/popupPortPOI.do?voyageCode=S517&tourCode=&travelOrder=A&portid=BNE
```

I'm interested in using a regex expression to extract the voyage code.  In this case I'd be looking for it to return the following values:

```
S515

S515

D520

D520

S517
```

Comment: In what environment/language? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is pretty simple, why haven't you tried anything? `.\d+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
((?<=voyageCode=)[^=&\s]+)|((?<=portid=)[^=&\s]+)
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/oA5mB3/3)

Comment: If I wanted to get results like the below from the string above, is there a regex that could deliver it?

S515 SYD
D520 JFM
S517 BNE